# How to locate HOMO-LUMO molecular orbitals in Transmisson and PDOS graphs?

Tags: ab-initio-calculations, siesta, electronic-transport

I have done TBtrans calculations using SIESTA (v4.0.2) and plotted transmission, as well as  PDOS Vs Energy graphs. I want to know how to locate HOMO-LUMO MOs in those graphs (or) how can I say which peak is HOMO-LUMO in those graphs? Does this requires different software or can I do this with just SIESTA?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question?